# Can we post product details directly from third party catalog to OCI SAP SRM?

Tags: sap-srm

We are supplier for one retailer, who is using SAP SRM.
Retailer is using our system to place an order but wants to make the same order entry in their SAP also.

I have read OCI (Open Catalog Interface) of SAP.
http://www.attsuppliers.com/downloads/OCI_40_EN20030611.pdf

I understand that with OCI, we need to initiate transaction from SRM (Supplier Relationship Module) server to make an entry of order.

The flow I understand is:

1. We need to configure for third party catalog (one time process)
2. Browse that catalog with specifying filtering parameters
3. Select a product
4. Post a form specifically designed to post data to SRM server in the catalog with 'Return URL'
5. SRM server gets the posted data and makes an order entry in SAP SRM module

Is it possible to initiate the transaction directly from third party catalog and post product details with Return URL to SRM server?

Not sure whether Return URL fixed for a catalog or generated dynamically.

Basically, we want such flow of execution:

1. Retailer selects a product from our catalog
2. Generate an order in our system
3. At the same time we want to communicate with SRM server of their SAP and put an order in their system also, without initiating transaction from SRM server (i.e. this order should be placed automatically in SAP)

Please provide possible solutions or appropriate suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you understood the OCI process correct, but you want to integrate another process to it.

When the initial settings are made the usual process is:

1. The customer calls the OCI-catalogue of the provider and select materials
2. The selected materials (and prices...) are returned in a form to a return address (_HOOK_URL_).
3. The customer place an order in his system.
4. The order is send to the provider. This may be a fax... or in a full integrated EDI scenario an [IDOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDoc) (Idoc type ORDERS01 .. ORDERS05)
5. The provider gets the order idoc and confirms the order with an order response.

In your case: You use OCI to place the order in your system and an EDI-connection to place the order at SRM. Best you ask the SRM if he supports EDI-connections.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is SAP is providing such webservice/API through which, we can follow the same process but from third party catalog?

See here my another question related to this one: [Can we connect to SAP module SRM from third party catalog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912006/can-we-connect-to-sap-module-srm-from-third-party-catalog)

Comment: @KulinChoksi Did you manage to solve this scenario?